# Lightning lightning:verticalNavigation issue when resetting navigation data

Tags: lightning-aura-components

When the attribute value related to `<aura:iteration>` is get reset, this error is thrown.

> Uncaught rerender threw an error in 'aura:iteration' [Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null]

In following example, when "Submit" button is clicked, this error message is displayed. Not sure whether this is a limitation or an issue. I wasn't able to find any thing in known issues either.

[image]

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" >
    <aura:attribute name="navigationData" type="Object" description="The list of sections and their items." />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }" />
    <lightning:card title="Navigation">
    <lightning:verticalNavigation>
            <aura:iteration items="{! v.navigationData }" var="section">
                <lightning:verticalNavigationSection label="{! section.label }">
                    <aura:iteration items="{! section.items }" var="item">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{! !empty(item.icon) }">
                            <lightning:verticalNavigationItemIcon
                                label="{! item.label }"
                                name="{! item.name }"
                                iconName="{! item.icon }" />
                            <aura:set attribute="else">
                                <lightning:verticalNavigationItem
                                    label="{! item.label }"
                                    name="{! item.name }" />
                            </aura:set>
                        </aura:if>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:verticalNavigationSection>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:verticalNavigation> 

        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
        </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

## Controller

```
({
    init: function (component, event, helper) {
        var sections = [
          {
            label: "Reports",
            items: [
              {
                label: "Created by Me",
                name: "default_created"
              },
              {
                label: "Public Reports",
                name: "default_public"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            label: "Dashboards",
            items: [
              {
                label: "Favorites",
                name: "default_favorites",
                icon: "utility:favorite"
              },
              {
                label: "Most Popular",
                name: "custom_mostpopular"
              }
            ]
          }
        ];
        component.set('v.navigationData', sections);
    },

    handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var sections2 = [
          {
            label: "Reports2",
            items: [
              {
                label: "Created by Me2",
                name: "default_created2"
              },
              {
                label: "Public Reports2",
                name: "default_public2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            label: "Dashboards2",
            items: [
              {
                label: "Favorites2",
                name: "default_favorites2",
                icon: "utility:favorite"
              },
              {
                label: "Most Popular2",
                name: "custom_mostpopular2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ];
        component.set('v.navigationData', sections2);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have raised this with Salesforce support and now they have confirmed that this is fixed in the Winter 18 release.